# Facebook login with FirebaseUI for Android - how to get publish_actions permission?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebaseui

I want to make a facebook leaderboard, so I need to use the graph API for score. I have no problem to read the player's score. What is the best way to update the score of the player when his score changes ? At the moment, everytime the score changes I :
- read the current score with the graph API
- increase the score (for example +1 point if the player wins)
- update the score with the graph API

My issue is that I don't know how to get the publish_actions permission when the user logs in. I need it to update the score with the facebook graph API.

Here is my code :

```
                AuthUI.IdpConfig facebookIdp = new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER)
                        .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends", "publish_actions"))
                        .build();

                startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                .setProviders(Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                        facebookIdp))
                                .setTheme(R.style.loginTheme)
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
```

The problem is that .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends", "publish_actions")) do not gives me the publish_permission. It says "Cannot pass a publish or manage permission (publish_actions) to a request for read authorization".

So I understand that .setPermission works for read permissions only. How can I get the publish_actions permission for my Android app using FirebaseUI ?

Thank you,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got some bad news for you :(

FirebaseUI team has identified this as a missing feature that is blocked for implementation by the Graph API.

Rationale:
Facebook makes it intentionally hard to request read and publish permissions at the same time so it won't fit within the flow of FirebaseUI. The best thing to do is provide only your read permissions to FirebaseUI and then after the user has signed in ask again for the publish permissions (which is what Facebook's guidelines suggest)

See the Github issue for more information; https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/535